# Code hangs in RStudio and isn't added to environment

Tags: r, rstudio

My R Studio doesn't run code. When I run code, there is no error and the code appears in the console but it is not executed. I uninstalled and reinstalled R and R Studio several times but still it doesn't work. For example, I run this code:

```
s <- c(1,2,3,4) 
s
```

but the console shows this: `s <- c(1,2,3,4)`. Nothing is added to environment and I don't see `[1] 1 2 3 4` in return.

I am using RStudio Desktop 2021.09.1+372. My R version is 4.1.2.
Also, when I try to quite session, it freezes. I really don't know what is wrong with it. I was wondering if someone could help me.

Comment: Welcome. Usually it's worth filing a big report with Rstudio for these kind of things since it's hard for people to help here. https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues. PS. the plural for code is code, not codes :)

Comment: Can you copy/paste exactly what appears in the console? Does a new prompt appear waiting for new commands (ie, ">")? Have you loaded any existing code or package into your environment?

Comment: As I pointed out in my post, the console shows this: s <- c(1,2,3,4). Nothing could be added to environment. When I want to import a dataset, it just freezes.

Comment: It sounds computer specific, but hard to know without more info (e.g. screenshots). A bug report as suggested above could be helpful? Or if you sign up and test with RStudio cloud, do you see what you expect?